# try, catch and if error in a combo box with java and netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I assure you all that this is not homework.

I have a combo box:

```
try {
    double input = Double.valueOf(input1.getText());
    double output = 0;
```

My combo box code here:

```
 if (output < 2.50){
     answerField.setText("£2.50");

         }
         else{
     answerField.setText("£" + String.valueOf (fmt.format(output)));
      catch (Exception e) {    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
 "Please enter numbers in the fields.
 Numbers are 1 2 3 4 5 etc.",
 "Oooops!!!",
 JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

The problem I have is that when I run it like this it won't work.
if I take the if statement out and leave try catch in, it works
and also if I take the try and catch out it and leave only the if, it also works

When I run it using the above, I get this error:

```
catch without try
; expected
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: repeating, in a written form doesn't have such effect as in verbal form.

Comment: lol.

worth a try though

Comment: why the -1?

i know its a simple question but i'm sure many new programmers would makethis mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must close your else bracket, and then your try bracket:

```
try {
  if (..) {
     ...
  } else {
     ...
  }
} catch (Exception e) {..}
```

Comment: everything is closed. i've triple checked

Comment: sorry.

misunderstood what you said lol.

its working now.

thank you